# Where are Logic instruments located in High Sierra?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, logic

Trying to locate the logic instrument pack on my HD. Earlier versions had them in Library/app support/Logic, but no such file exists.

Comment: I wonder what exact version of the Logic app you installed and if you just managed to have a corrupt or partial installation. Have you tried removing the app and then re-installing it so that an installation log or failure might get presented to you explaining the error?

Answer (score 1):

```
/Library/Application Support/Logic/
```

---

How to find your root Library folder:

1. Open your startup disk in Finder, either by clicking the name of your startup disk (e.g. Macintosh HD) in the sidebar, or by pressing ⇧⌘G and entering /.

   [image]
2. You should have these 4 folders. Open Library.

   [image]

Comment: I dont have a logic file in library/app support. Must be located somewhere else.

Comment: @HidalgoJames I now notice that you're missing the first / when referring to the Library folder, are you checking the /Library folder in the root of the startup disk, or the Library folder in your home directory?

Comment: Or the installation of the app failed - see my comment about reinstalling Logic on the main question.

Comment: looking at user/library/app support/

Comment: @HidalgoJames Look in /Library, you get this from opening Macintosh HD, not your user folder

Comment: The instrument folder most be on the disk. It is taking up 75gb space

Comment: Sorry, not sure i understand what you mean. I only know of one library folder which I find through user folder. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @HidalgoJames See edit to my answer